# Replace a text within a sentence in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sorry for this question that seems really stupid but i'm really confused with it

The sentence :

```
 String myline = "<form name='oldvalue' action='old_value' method='get'>"
```

Expected result :

```
  <form name='oldvalue' action='new_value' method='get'>
```

I want to replace the value of the text between quotes that follows action.

I dont want to use myLine.Replace because the value of the action attribute in the sentence is random, and i don't care of it. Whathever its value i want to be replaced by `new_value`

How can I achieve this ! Thankyou.

Comment: Is it tottaly random or do you have it stored inside a variable?

Comment: sorry for my String.Format() answer, it's not the case when you already have a value inside the quotes. Go with Regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

String myline = "<form name='oldvalue' action='old_value' method='get'>";
String new_value = "new_value";
Regex.Replace(myline, "action='(.*?)'", new_value);
```

---

### UPDATE:

This code actually returns `<form name='oldvalue' new_value method='get'>`

*([iedone](http://ideone.com/rU7pV2) as @Nacereddine mentioned)*

If you want to return `<form name='oldvalue' action='new_value' method='get'>` use this:

```
Regex.Replace(myline, @"(action=')(.*?)(')", "$1"+new_value+"$3");
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this with an entire HTML document ? there isn't only one string to be modified but i have an entire document..

Comment: Yes, if `myline` will be your entire HTML it will also work :)

Comment: Regular Expression are very powerful when handle correctly. They allow you to find any kind of combination of character or string within a library if you want.

Comment: Same thing here : After replacement this is what you get `<form name='oldvalue' new_value>` http://ideone.com/Yt50Mu

Comment: @Nacereddine Yes, i fixed it, forgot the '?' to make it non greedy.

Comment: @Nacereddine Sorry guys for the confusion, i updated the answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

If this line is the only input, you can simply use a regular expression to change `action='(.*?)'` to whatever you like.

```
String input = "<form name='oldvalue' action='old_value' method='get'>";
String newAction = "action='new_value'";
var s = Regex.Replace(input, "action='(.*?)'", newAction);
```

Output:

```
s: "<form name='oldvalue' action='new_value' method='get'>"
```

However, if the bigger picture actually is to modify an HTML document, you should definitely take a look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This returns `action='old_value' method='get'`

Comment: He's not - '(.*)' will take the longest string it can match, and since "." references all characters, including the apostrophe it will match the method='get' as well

Comment: @Nacereddine Oops, seems you're right, sorry. Made it non-greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Regex.Replace method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/xwewhkd1.aspx

Should be something like

```
new Regex("action='.*?'").Replace(myline,"action='new_value'");
```

**Edit**: fixed regex as suggested by Nacereddine

Comment: You're replacing `method='get'` too. add `?` to fix your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
new Regex("action='([^\']*)'").Replace(myLine, "action='new_value'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) as shown bellow. You also manipulate all attribute as you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<form name='oldvalue' action='old_value' method='get' />");
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("form"))
            {
                node.Attributes["action"].Value = "new_value";
            }
            Console.Write(doc.OuterXml);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Html is usually not (parsable as) XML. Html Agility Pack does a better job at this.